# What's the meaning of these MAC addresses in macOS’s route table?

Tags: macos, mac, routing

From `netstat -nr` I get this "crap":

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
192.168.2.12       dc:1b:a1:98:31:4f  UHLWIi            en0   1185
192.168.2.14       a0:e7:ae:62:3:3d   UHLWIi            en0   1187
192.168.2.15       50:2:91:28:12:f4   UHLWI             en0   1196
192.168.2.23       14:91:38:b:c8:97   UHLWI             en0   1191
192.168.2.25       14:c1:4e:3a:d4:79  UHLWIi            en0   1187
192.168.2.27       60:55:f9:e1:81:9a  UHLWI             en0   1194
192.168.2.28       38:8b:59:70:6a:4d  UHLWIi            en0   1187
```

These routes are blocking my connections to those addresses, and if I remove them, then I can finally ping those addresses.

First question is why the gateway is a MAC address?

BTW, those MAC addresses are NOT corresponding to the network adapter's MAC addresses on the devices assigned with those IP addresses.

Second question is since when MAC addresses can be used as gateway addresses?

I tried to add a route like that, but the route command refuses anything that isn't an IPv4/6 address.

Answer (score 1):

### That netstat output is perfectly normal and is not the root cause of your connectivity problems.

Your Mac's en0 interface presumably has an IP address on the 192.168.2.x subnet, so it considers those addresses local, so it is using ARP to find those hosts' MAC addresses and sending packets to them directly over whatever LAN en0 is connected to. By displaying those local LAN hosts' MAC addresses in the "gateway" column, it's just saving you a from having to use `arp -an` to see the ARP table data for those hosts.

If those ARP mappings look incorrect to you, then something else must be wrong on your network.

Off the top of my head, some things I'd look into might include:

1. Maybe you have two separate LANs that are both using 192.168.2.x? Like you accidentally have the same subnet on both sides of a router, or maybe you have two separate NAT gateways each using the 192.168.2.x subnet as the NAT private subnet, and your Mac's en0 is connected to the "other" NAT gateways private/LAN side?
2. Maybe you have a misconfigured IP address or subnet mask on your Mac (or maybe somewhere else?), so it's treating those IP addresses as local when you really wanted it to be on a separate subnet and have to use a router to reach those hosts?
3. Use an IEEE OUI lookup tool to find the vendors for those MAC addresses and see if you can figure out which devices are claiming those IP addresses. I actually just did that for you, and it seems like they are as follows:

---

- .12 is an Intel device (maybe an Intel NIC or Wi-Fi adapter in a PC)
- .14 is an Arris device (Arris makes cable modems/gateways and other networking equipment)
- .15 and .27 are both "Espressif". That company makes chips for lots of IoT/smarthome devices, so this could be a smart plug or smart lightbulb or something. For example, I have a "Fellow Stagg ‎EKG Pro Electric Kettle Studio Edition" that uses an Espressif OUI on its Wi-Fi interface.
- .23 is an Amazon device (Fire TV stick? Echo?)
- .25 and .28 are Google devices (Chromecast sticks? Google Nest devices of some sort? Google Wifi APs?)

These all seem like reasonable devices to have on a home network, so I don't think any ARP spoofing/poisoning is going on, and I don't think MAC address privacy randomization is happening since the "locally administered" bit (the 2's place bit in the first byte of each MAC address) is not set for any of these.

Comment: 1. No I don't
2. I didn't configure those IP addresses manually, and I do have only one LAN
3. I tried, and thanks for proactively looking! They seem legit, however I wonder why would my macbook need routes to them.. Besides one more entry - not in the list I pasted up there - isn't the actual MAC address shown on that device's network adapter's properties. It's about a Win11 desktop that I can't reach because of that route, and removing the route resolves the connectivity issue.

Comment: @frakie So is the connectivity problem only with the Win11 box you didn't list? How many of the 7 devices listed can you successfully ping without deleting that host's route? Also, can you track down what device owns the MAC address the Mac gets for the Win11 box? If it's one of your router's MAC address, then there could be a subnet mask mismatch problem going on somewhere, and a router's trying to do Proxy ARP or ICMP Redirects or something to try to make up for it, but it's not working out for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your question can be fully answered as part of it depends on your network and correcting your understanding of how this part of the TCP/IP stack works.

MAC addresses bind to interfaces.  They are fairly easy to fake and indeed some OS's do this as a matter of course to increase security - this may explain some of the MAC addresses you are seeing.

**At this layer of connectivity, nothing is known about gateways or other devices - the gateway will have multiple interfaces - likely with different MAC addresses for each.   The IP address is associated with the MAC address, and the way the gateway is reached is identical to all other devices.   All that differs is that routing for other devices can be directed through the IP of the gateway - critically however, computers still need to resolve the IP address of the gateway in order to talk to it using the "ethernet protocol"**

This still leaves the question of why some destinations IP addresses are associated with MAC addresses of devices not currently on your network.   It would be reasonable to speculate that the DHCP server has a small range of IP addresses set aside and is reusing addresses - if that is the case you should look at increasing the size of the IP range in the DHCP server.    Also check that Apple devices connecting to your network don't have MAC RANDOMIZATION turned on - as that will cause IP addresses to change and will fill up your DHCP mappings.

Comment: One clarification: those entries pertain IP addresses actually in use, and those entries are re-created (as you see them) after deleting them and restarting the network service, therefore messing up with my connectivity to those devices from my macbook.

Answer (score 0):

> First question is why the gateway is a MAC address?

macOS uses the same table both for routes and neighbor (ARP) caching, which it can do because (see next part).

> Second question is since when MAC addresses can be used as gateway addresses?

In a sense, since forever. The gateway address is never put anywhere in the IP header; literally the *only purpose* of the gateway address in a routing table is to be subsequently translated to some kind of MAC address for the Ethernet header.

So e.g. when you have a route "via 192.168.1.1", that really just means "do an ARP query for 192.168.1.1 and send towards the resulting MAC address". And a local subnet route (with no gateway) is almost the same, meaning "do an ARP query for the destination itself".

Considering that, the macOS behavior of cloning¹ the local subnet route into individual host routes with their resolved MAC addresses – as opposed to having a completely separate "ARP cache" table – is perhaps unusual but by no means strange.

¹ (Per the manual, `W` means a cloned route – a practice on BSD systems for caching more specific routes based on a broader subnet route.)

Comment: Thanks, I guess then the real question is why those entries are added in the first place, and why they contain wrong information - even after deleting them, restarting the network service brings them back.

Comment: No idea regarding that. The AskDifferent site might have more macOS experts.